# Negation in np.select() condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, negation

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'var1': ['a', 'b', 'c',np.nan, np.nan],
                   'var2': [1, 2, np.nan , 4, np.nan]
                 })



conditions = [
    (not(pd.isna(df["var1"]))) & (not(pd.isna(df["var2"]))),
    (pd.isna(df["var1"])) & (pd.isna(df["var2"]))]

choices = ["No missing", "Both missing"]

df['Result'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

Output:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Problem is with line `(not(pd.isna(df["var1"]))) & (not(pd.isna(df["var2"])))`. This line should give `TRUE` when in both `var1` and `var2` in not a `NaN` value. Problem here is with negation, because with conditions without negation there is no problem.

**Question:**  How can to correct `(not(pd.isna(df["var1"]))) & (not(pd.isna(df["var2"])))` line so in case when  in both `var1` and `var2` in not a `NaN` value the condition should give `TRUE`?

Comment: why not use `df.notna()` instead: `conditions = [
    (df["var1"].notna() & df['var2'].notna()),
    (pd.isna(df["var1"])) & (pd.isna(df["var2"]))]`

Comment: @anky_91 That worked, thank you. That much better way for this particular case. But I am also interested how to properly use negation for future use. What is wrong with my negation?

Comment: you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44345755/9840637) answer for better explanation on why your negation doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
conditions = [(~pd.isna(df["var1"]) & ~pd.isna(df["var2"])),
               (pd.isna(df["var1"]) &  pd.isna(df["var2"]))]
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. what is the difference between with `.values` and without it? Which way is better and why?

Comment: Also can you please provide any link with `~` operator explanation (documentation)?

Comment: Thank you. What is the advantage of using array instead of Series in this case?

Comment: '.values' converts it from a Series to an array (not required). For more about "~" see here: wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators