# Compare multiple pandas columns (1st and 2nd, after 3rd and 4rth, after etc) with vectorization (better) or other method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

This code compares based on `condition` the `var1` and `var2` and creates `Results1` based on `choices` (this code works well):

```
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas?answertab=oldest#tab-top
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099141/negation-in-np-select-condition

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating one column from two columns. We asume that in every row there is one NaN and one value and that value fills new column.
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'var1': ['a', 'b', 'c',np.nan, np.nan],
                   'var2': [1, 2, np.nan , 4, np.nan], 
                   'var3': [np.nan , "x", np.nan, "y", "z"],
                   'var4': [np.nan , 4, np.nan, 5, 6],
                   'var5': ["a", np.nan , "b", np.nan, "c"],
                   'var6': [1, np.nan , 2, np.nan, 3]
                 })


#all conditions that are connected with logical operators (&, |, etc) should be in ().
conditions = [
    (df["var1"].notna()) & (df['var2'].notna()),
    (pd.isna(df["var1"])) & (pd.isna(df["var2"])),
    (df["var1"].notna()) & (pd.isna(df["var2"])),
    (pd.isna(df["var1"])) & (df['var2'].notna())]

choices = ["Both values", np.nan, df["var1"], df["var2"]]

df['Result1'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

`df` looks like as it should:

```
|    | var1   |   var2 | var3   |   var4 | var5   |   var6 | Result1     |
|---:|:-------|-------:|:-------|-------:|:-------|-------:|:------------|
|  0 | a      |      1 | nan    |    nan | a      |      1 | Both values |
|  1 | b      |      2 | x      |      4 | nan    |    nan | Both values |
|  2 | c      |    nan | nan    |    nan | b      |      2 | c           |
|  3 | nan    |      4 | y      |      5 | nan    |    nan | 4           |
|  4 | nan    |    nan | z      |      6 | c      |      3 | nan         |
```

Now I want to compare multiple pandas columns (in my example `var1` and `var2`, after `var3` and `var4`, after `var5` and `var6`) and based on `condition` and `choices` create corresponding `Results` column (in my example `Result1`, `Result2`, `Result3`). I thought the best way should be to use vectorization (because of better performance). The `df` I want to get should look like:

```
|    | var1   |   var2 | var3   |   var4 | var5   |   var6 | Result1     | Result2     | Result3     |
|---:|:-------|-------:|:-------|-------:|:-------|-------:|:------------|:------------|:------------|
|  0 | a      |      1 | nan    |    nan | a      |      1 | Both values | nan         | Both values |
|  1 | b      |      2 | x      |      4 | nan    |    nan | Both values | Both values | nan         |
|  2 | c      |    nan | nan    |    nan | b      |      2 | c           | nan         | Both values |
|  3 | nan    |      4 | y      |      5 | nan    |    nan | 4           | Both values | nan         |
|  4 | nan    |    nan | z      |      6 | c      |      3 | nan         | Both values | Both values |
```

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating one column from two columns. We asume that in every row there is one NaN and one value and that value fills new column.
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'var1': ['a', 'b', 'c',np.nan, np.nan],
                   'var2': [1, 2, np.nan , 4, np.nan], 
                   'var3': [np.nan , "x", np.nan, "y", "z"],
                   'var4': [np.nan , 4, np.nan, 5, 6],
                   'var5': ["a", np.nan , "b", np.nan, "c"],
                   'var6': [1, np.nan , 2, np.nan, 3]
                 })


col1 = ["var1", "var3", "var5"]
col2 = ["var2", "var4", "var6"]
colR = ["Result1", "Result2", "Result3"]

#all conditions that are connected with logical operators (&, |, etc) should be in ().
conditions = [
    (df[col1].notna()) & (df[col2].notna()),
    (pd.isna(df[col1])) & (pd.isna(df[col2])),
    (df[col1].notna()) & (pd.isna(df[col2])),
    (pd.isna(df[col1])) & (df[col2].notna())]

choices = ["Both values", np.nan, df[col1], df[col2]]

df[colR] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

Buy it gave me error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

**Question:** How to achieve my goal with vectorization (preferable because of better performance) or other method?

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `pandas` DataFrames force alignment on the index, but `df[col1]` and `df[col2]` have no overlapping columns.

In this case, you really want to work with the underlying numpy arrays. Also because `.isnull()` is the opposite of `notnull` you can simplify this a lot. We'll concat to add the new columns back.

```
col1 = ["var1", "var3", "var5"]
col2 = ["var2", "var4", "var6"]
colR = ["Result1", "Result2", "Result3"]

s1 = df[col1].isnull().to_numpy()
s2 = df[col2].isnull().to_numpy()

conditions = [~s1 & ~s2, s1 & s2, ~s1 & s2, s1 & ~s2]
choices = ["Both values", np.nan, df[col1], df[col2]]

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.select(conditions, choices), columns=colR, index=df.index)], axis=1)
```

---

```
  var1  var2 var3  var4 var5  var6      Result1      Result2      Result3
0    a   1.0  NaN   NaN    a   1.0  Both values          NaN  Both values
1    b   2.0    x   4.0  NaN   NaN  Both values  Both values          NaN
2    c   NaN  NaN   NaN    b   2.0            c          NaN  Both values
3  NaN   4.0    y   5.0  NaN   NaN            4  Both values          NaN
4  NaN   NaN    z   6.0    c   3.0          NaN  Both values  Both values
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain more why there should be used `null` related methods and instead of `NA` ones?

Comment: @vasili111 `DataFrame.isna` is an alias of `DataFrame.isnull` so they do the exact same thing. I personally prefer the `isnull` wording because I think it's more precise in describing what's happening. `pandas` also has the methods `pd.isnull(array-like-object)`, which can operate on array-like objects. You could use those too, i.e. `pd.isnull(Series)`, but you people generally use the DataFrame/Series methods instead `Series.isnull()`

Comment: Do you have any thought why your code can give nan string when using `np.nan` and missing value when using `pd.NA`? More here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570118/difference-between-nan-and-nan-and-error-that-maybe-caused-by-that