# .isnull() vs .isna() for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

`.isnull()` vs `.isna()` for pandas.

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'object': ['a', 'b', 'c',pd.NA],
                   'numeric': [1, 2, np.nan , 4],
                 })
```

creates data frame `df` that looks like:

```
|    | object   |   numeric | categorical   |
|---:|:---------|----------:|:--------------|
|  0 | a        |         1 | d             |
|  1 | b        |         2 | nan           |
|  2 | c        |       nan | f             |
|  3 | <NA>     |         4 | g             |
```

Testing `.isnull()` and `.isna()`:

```
pd.isnull(df.iloc[3,0])
Out[165]: True

pd.isnull(df.iloc[2,1])
Out[166]: True

pd.isna(df.iloc[3,0])
Out[167]: True

pd.isna(df.iloc[2,1])
Out[168]: True
```

Here both `.isnull()` and `.isna()` give same result.

**Question:** Which one to use with pandas and why to use? What are main advantages and disadvantages of each of them with pandas?

Comment: `isnull` is an alias of `isna`.  [The documentation states this.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)

Comment: Copy of [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37878/difference-between-isna-and-isnull-in-pandas)

Comment: Use `isna` as it is two characters shorter than `isnull` and therefore cooler

Comment: Found answer here justt now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101845/compare-multiple-pandas-columns-1st-and-2nd-after-3rd-and-4rth-after-etc-wit/60102672?noredirect=1#comment106324219_60102672

Comment: Next time, please do a Google search before posting posts.

Comment: @nakE I did but could not find.

Comment: If you google the title of your question, the first two results both give the correct answer.  The next place you should look is the documentation, which also gives the correct answer, and next, [the code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/generic.py#L7269), which also shows they are the exact same.

Comment: @Rene it's the other way around.